# Magento2 : How to show custom notice message in checkout page on page load?

Tags: magento2, checkout, modal-popup, global-messages, magento2.3.6

I want to display Custom Notice message in `Popup` on **page load** in Checkout page.

Comment: Hello @Fena do you want to add this message oin every page load?

Comment: @WaqarAli No, i just want display on checkout page only.

Comment: are you using magento default checkout or any 3rd party extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add popup code in onepage.phtml

override this file in your theme

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml
```

to

```
/app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml
```

and add below code

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
], function($){
    return function (){
        $(document).on("ready",function (){
          alert({
           title: $.mage.__('Some title'),
           content: $.mage.__('Some content'),
           actions: {
           always: function(){}
           }
        });            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Custom Module as Follows

> Vendor\ModuleName\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

then

> Vendor\ModuleName\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
       <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Override checkout_index_index.xml in your module and define your own shipping component

> pp/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" after="-" name="custom_popup" template="Vendor_ModuleName::popup.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body
```

> 

nexlty in your

> Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates\popup.phtml

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "customPopup" : {)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now in your

> Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customPopup: 'Vendor_ModuleName/js/popup'        }
    }
}
```

Now Create a Logic of Ajax Request in Your Js file

> Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\web\js\sendSms.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert'
], function($){
    return function (){
        $(document).on("ready",function (){
          alert({
           title: $.mage.__('Some title'),
           content: $.mage.__('Some content'),
           actions: {
           always: function(){}
           }
        });            
        });
    }
```